# Generating random string (for unique code) keeps returning the same random string

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a `Test` model where each test can be identified by a unique randomly-generated string:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

class Test(models.Model):
    code_length = 7
    code = models.CharField(max_length=code_length, editable=False, default=generate_id(code_length))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Code: {} | Username: {} | Test: {}".format(self.code, self.user.username, self.name)

def generate_id(length):
    return get_random_string(length)
```

Tbh, it was working good before. It started to "bugged-out" after I updated my Django from Django 1.x to Django 3.x and I also cleared all the records of the `Test` model in django-admin (I want to have a fresh and clean database for testing). Right now, whenever I try and create a new `Test`, it's `code` is literally the same with all other new `Tests` that I create:

[image]

I think I haven't done anything to it other than those two changes I made. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not *call* the function, since then the default will take the *result* of the funcation call.

You thus construct a function:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

CODE_LENGTH = 7

def generate_id_length():
    return get_random_string(CODE_LENGTH)

class Test(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=CODE_LENGTH,
        editable=False,
        #          no parenthesis ↓
        default=generate_id_length
    )
```

if you do not want to move `CODE_LENGTH` outside the `Test` class, you can use:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

def generate_id_length():
    return get_random_string(Test.code_length)

class Test(models.Model):
    code_length = 7
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=CODE_LENGTH,
        editable=False,
        #          no parenthesis ↓
        default=generate_id_length
    )
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much!!! It worked! I still can't accept the the answer for the next 8 minutes. I have a small question, when the `code_length` was transferred right above the other codes, this was declared global right? That's why it was also in all caps? (I'm fairly new to Python and Django)

Comment: @DranDev: well you need to use the `CODE_LENGTH` in the `generate_id_length`, so we need to move it out of the `Test` function, or you can use `Test.code_length` in the function. The uppercase are the PEP-8 guidelines that say that constants are written in *screaming* snake case: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/